# How to retrieve data from non-WSDL using SoapClient

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

There is a non-wsdl web service URL. This web service takes some authentication parameters directly in URL with XML format :

*[Snip: I changed my actual domain with `example`]*

```
http://example.com/WSV2/StaticData.php?xml=<StaticDataRequest><Header><Code>TT4533</Code><Username>skyman211</Username><Password>ammkj43</Password></Header><Body><GetStaticData>cities</GetStaticData><ExtraParams><CountryCode>98</CountryCode></ExtraParams></Body></StaticDataRequest>
```

Which returns cities details with following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticDataResponse>
   <Country code="98" />
   <Cities>
      <City code="320">
         <Name>Tehran</Name>
      </City>
      <City code="1907">
         <Name>Shiraz</Name>
      </City>
      <City code="9971">
         <Name>Bandar Abbas</Name>
      </City>
   </Cities>
</StaticDataResponse>
```

Now, I need to access that URL and retrieve cities details(`code` and `name`) by using SoapClient.

I read many thread about connecting to a non-WSDL web service using SoapClient, but I wasn't successful.

Here is what I tried so far, and I'm sure it's incomplete :

```
$URL = 'http://example.com/WSV2/StaticData.php?xml=<StaticDataRequest><Header><Code>TT4533</Code><Username>skyman211</Username><Password>ammkj43</Password></Header><Body><GetStaticData>cities</GetStaticData><ExtraParams><CountryCode>67</CountryCode></ExtraParams></Body></StaticDataRequest>';

$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location' => $URL,
    'uri'      => "http://example.com/WSV2/",
    'trace'    => 1,
    ));

$return = $client->__soapCall();
```

Please tell me how can I retrieve cities `code` and `name` by SoapClient?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of SoapClient. `file_get_contents()` retrieves all you need :

```
$URL = 'http://example.com/WSV2/StaticData.php?xml=<StaticDataRequest><Header><Code>TT4533</Code><Username>skyman211</Username><Password>ammkj43</Password></Header><Body><GetStaticData>cities</GetStaticData><ExtraParams><CountryCode>67</CountryCode></ExtraParams></Body></StaticDataRequest>';

$data = file_get_contents($URL);
```

Now, `$data` is a string variable with all cities details that retrieved by the Web Service.

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r(htmlspecialchars($data), true) . '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticDataResponse>
   <Country code="98" />
   <Cities>
      <City code="320">
         <Name>Tehran</Name>
      </City>
      <City code="1907">
         <Name>Shiraz</Name>
      </City>
      <City code="9971">
         <Name>Bandar Abbas</Name>
      </City>
   </Cities>
</StaticDataResponse>
```